# Mongoose disconnect when calling startSession()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is my db config

```
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  replicaSet: "rs",
```

Connection 0 was disconnected when calling `startSession`

Comment: Could you post more information about your issue? Code snippets maybe?

Comment: @Vishwak I am having a similar issue. Trying to test my create user api.
```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

createUser = async (req, res) => {
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();
  session.startTransaction();
  ...

```

I tried using https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server#simple-mochachai-test-example using replicaSet but I always get back to the same error.

Comment: @Vishwak are you using Nestjs by any chance ?

Comment: @AbishekKumar, i am using Nodejs